# Find exactly two alphabetical characters [a-zA-Z] before a pattern, exclude all non word characters in between

Tags: regex, perl

I need to find two alphabetical characters before a five digit number in a string.

Example -

```
Revert changes made on _AB : 12342  
AB12342 reverted the changes
Revert the changes onab :_ 12342 id
```

In all the above cases i need the output as `AB12342`

I tried the following regex

```
if ($msg =~ /([a-zA-Z]{2})(\d{5})/)

if ($msg =~ /([a-zA-Z]{2})(.*)?(\d{5})/)

if ($msg =~ /([a-zA-Z]{2})(.*)?(\d{5})/)
```

In the first case it considered only 2 consecutive characters before the match. So I tried using the `.*` pattern which gave me the first two characters on the entire string. So i tried with the greedy operator as in the third line, but it still did not work. I don't know where it is going wrong.

Comment: did you want `ab12342` in your second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without converting to upper case, use:

```
$subject =~ s/([a-z]{2})[^\da-z]+(\d{5})/$1$2/ig;
```

- The `i` flag makes the regex case-insensitive
- `([a-z]{2})` captures two letters to Group 1
- `[^\da-z]+` matches any number of characters that are neither letters nor digits
- `(\d{5})` captures the five digits to Group 2
- `$1$2` replaces this with Group 1 + Group 2 (removing everything in between)

To convert to upper case, we need to use `uc()` in the lambda. See the output at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/AAEKH2).

```
$regex = '(?i)([a-z]{2})[^\da-z]+(\d{5})';
$subject = ' _AB : 12342  onab :_ 12342 ';
($replaced = $subject) =~ s/$regex/
         { uc($1) . $2; }  /eg;
print $replaced . "\n";
```

**Removing the Prefix**

Please note that the strings are correctly replaced, but the variables keep their prefix: `_AB12342` and `onAB12342`. I am happy to remove any prefix too, for example any non-space characters, if you think that it is safe.

Comment: FYI, added Perl code and online demo that makes sure the first two characters are upper case. Please let me know if  you have any questions. :)

Comment: Thank u :) I will try them.. I don't need to replace.. Just need the two letters and the number as output.. This works.. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will capture the last two alphabets which are present just before the five digit number.

```
.*([A-Za-z]{2}).*?(\d{5}).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pX0gC6)

Comment: @user2552451 if it works then accept anyone working answer from these answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change `(.*)?` to `[^a-zA-Z]*` to exclude all non word character.

```
$msg =~ /([a-zA-Z]{2})[^a-zA-Z]*\d{5}/
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
while (my $msg = <DATA>) { chomp $msg;
    if ($msg =~ /([a-zA-Z]{2})\s*:?\s*_?\s*(\d{5})/) {
        printf("%s: %s%d\n", $msg, uc $1, $2);
    }   
}

__DATA__
Revert changes made on _AB : 12342
AB12342 reverted the changes
Revert the changes onab :_ 12342 id
```

*Gives:*

```
Revert changes made on _AB : 12342: AB12342
AB12342 reverted the changes: AB12342
Revert the changes onab :_ 12342 id: AB12342
```